# xcode treating catching an error as a test failure

Tags: xcode, swift, unit-testing

I've written the following function:

```
func sendMessage(message:Dictionary<String,AnyObject>) {
    do {
        let json = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(message, options: [])
        let jsonStr = NSString(data: json, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        self.wsSource.writeString(jsonStr as! String)
    } catch let err as NSError {
        Rc2LogError ("error sending json message on websocket:\(err)")
    }
}
```

Here is a unit test that should pass:

```
func testSendMessageFailure() {
    let dict = ["foo":wspace!, "bar":22]
    session!.sendMessage(dict)
    XCTAssertNil(wsSrc.lastStringWritten)
}
```

But the test fails with the message:

```
test failure: -[Rc2SessionTests testSendMessageFailure()] failed: failed: caught "NSInvalidArgumentException", "Invalid type in JSON write (Rc2.Rc2Workspace)"
```

That isn't a failure. It is what I expect! Does this mean it is impossible to write a unit test that calls a function that has an error handler that handles the error?

How can I tell XCTest/Xcode that a caught error/exception does not mean a test failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`do-catch` statements are only for catching error thrown by the function. They do not catch exceptions. Exceptions are used to show that there is a programming error.

> If obj will not produce valid JSON, an exception is thrown. This exception is thrown prior to parsing and represents a programming error, not an internal error. You should check whether the input will produce valid JSON before calling this method by using `isValidJSONObject:`.

Source: [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/dataWithJSONObject:options:error:)

---

What is happening is that `message` is not an object that can be represented in json. My guess would be that `wspace` contains a type that can not be converted to json.

Comment: Yes, it intentionally contains a non-serializable object. I wasn't familiar with isValidJSONObject:, which I can call to get the functionality I want.